# Oracle nullable and non nullable column in a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, nullable, sql-view

I have a table in Oracle. This table has amongst others: EMPLOYEE_ID (NUMBER, Nullable, but number of NULLs is 0) and EMPLOYEE_NUMBER (VARCHAR2, Nullable, but number of NULLs is 0).

Now I create a view on this table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW APPS.XXKE_L2E_EMPLOYEE
(
   PERSON_ID,
   EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
   ...
)
AS
   SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
          EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
          ...
     FROM xxke.xxke_employees e
          INNER JOIN xxke.xxke_organizations o ON e.organization_id = o.organization_id
          INNER JOIN xxke.xxke_operating_units ou ON e.org_id = ou.org_id;

ALTER VIEW APPS.XXKE_L2E_EMPLOYEE
ADD CONSTRAINT XXKE_L2E_EMPLOYEE_V_PK
PRIMARY KEY(PERSON_ID) DISABLE;
```

How on earth is it possible that in that view PERSON_ID becomes **Nullable** (even when using NVL trick), but EMPLOYEE_NUMBER is **NOT Nullable**

**QUESTION**:
How can I make Oracle to create the view in a way, so the PERSON_ID column becomes NOT Nullable in the view? Or how can I make my WCF oData service query this view. Currently after updating the edmx file I get the following:

Errors: Oracle.ssdl(227,6) : error 0075: Key Part: 'PERSON_ID' for type XXKE_L2E_EMPLOYEE is not valid. All parts of the key must be non nullable.

Comment: Could it be cause you are using NVL on one of the columns and not the otehr?

Comment: You've allowed your outrage to get in the way of providing a clear question.  Please explain what actually is happening and ghow that diofferes from what you would like to happen.

Comment: It's the same with NVL or without it. Moreover, this is what I get when I try to access the view from Entity Framework, after updating edmx: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Oracle.ssdl(227,6) : error 0075: Key Part: 'PERSON_ID' for type XXKE_L2E_EMPLOYEE is not valid. All parts of the key must be non nullable. Best part is that in VS2010 this column is automatically set to non-nullable and marked as a PK...

Comment: @MichalB.: Wait, is it SQL Server or EF telling you that the columns are nullable?  Check how the view is in SQL management Studio

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11097839/266304 (cross-posted as http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19484/847 too). Are you saying you need the metadata for the view to show the columns as `not null` for EF's benefit, as in that question?

Comment: @Limey: It's Oracle, I use Toad and Toad tells me that PERSON_ID is Nullable, but EMPLOYEE_NUMBER is not nullable. In VS2010 both are not nullable and PERSON_ID is marked as PK. But I still get the error "...All parts of the key must be non nullable..."

Comment: @AlexPoole I am not sure, but I EF complains about Key part being nullable. In EF they are automatically set as not nullable, but I still get this error. I didn't have this problem when I used EMPLOYEE_NUMBER as PK (it's marked not nullable in the view), but it's not a PK, so EF does unpredictable things (e.g. mixes up data for the record with the same EMPLOYEE_NUMBER)

Comment: Are either `employee_id` or `employee_number` PKs on the underlying table? I suspect that might explain the different behaviour, since the PK is not nullable even if it wasn't created with an explicit `NOT NULL` clause. Adding a `DESC` of the underlying tables and the final view might clarify things. The two previous questions have several approaches, are any of them possible for you?

Comment: No they are not PK's nor a part of a PK. I read the link to StackOverlow that you put in your comment, but it's not feasible for me, because I cannot change the table nor can I create one...I just do not understand why EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ends up NON NULLABLE and PERSON_ID Nullable. Both are nullable in the table and neither of them is PK in the original table...

Comment: Frankly we can't understand "why EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ends up NON NULLABLE" either. Oracle Views inherit their not null constraints from teh underlying table. So the view shouyld only show NOT NULL for that column if the source column in the table is NOT NULL.

Comment: @MichalB.: Just noticed that you were adding a key to your view.  Keys on views are usually not needed (as they get the keys from the underlining tables).  What happens if you remove all key references (not just diable)?

Comment: @Limey: They are needed in this case, because this view is used by Entity Framework and EF requires PK. It must be disabled, because otherwise it's not possible to create a PK on a view. Without the key references it's the same...

Comment: @MichalB.: I will have to give it a try, cause in my limited use of EF, I have never run across this issue.  Could it be cause you are renaming the columns so the table keys arn't coming thru?

Comment: @MichalB.: So i went in and did a simple test (albeit, in SQL server) and i was able to create a view, reference it by EF and pull that data without adding any other keys to the view, just selecting the ones from the table.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it becomes nullable is when creating view query you used nvl on employee_id. The employee is not nullable in the query so that is why it is not.  In a view, oracle makes the resulting column nullable.  Views are not static but just a query.  If you want to not have the issue you can create a materialized view of the table with the nvl pre applied in query  then query will not have null possible selected.  You can then do indexes and queries will be significantly faster.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It's the same with or without NVL function. I actually should have the NVL removed for the sake of this question. It only brings unnecessary confusion...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your column in the view to be non-nullable, then inner join with the table that contains this column as primary key and select (in this case) PERSON_ID from that table in the view definition. That resolves the problem.