# Generate unique ID that is NOT NULL in a Oracle view with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, nullable, oracle12c, sql-view

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`, that are related to each other with a one-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  foo NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_bar_foo FOREIGN KEY (foo) REFERENCES foo (id)
);
```

Now I want to create a view with a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables, where every row in the view has a unique `id`, so I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE my_view AS
SELECT ORA_HASH(foo.id || '~' || bar.id) id
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.foo = foo.id
```

My problem is that the column `id` of the view becomes nullable, even though it could never have the value `NULL`. For this to work with another application, I need to have a unique non-nullable id in the view.

Can I somehow fool Oracle into making the column non-nullable? Or is there some other way to generate a unique id that is non-nullable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097839/how-to-create-a-not-null-column-in-a-view

Comment: I think you can do this with a materialized view, but not with a regular view.

Answer (score 1):

What about instead of building your id from the ids of the two existing tables, build it based on sys_guid()?
Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view my_view AS
SELECT sys_guid() id
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.foo = foo.id
```

Comment: The column is still nullable.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your data? I'm unable to get those null values. To be frank, even using your function I couldn't get any null values.

Comment: @Joevan . . . create a table as `create table t as select * from my_view` and you'll see the `NULL` values.

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. I ran your statement and it worked like a charm :-/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I also get the column as nullable on 12c.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. You have Oracle 12. I have Oracle 11. Maybe this is an issue with your specific version.

Comment: @Jodevan . . . Very interesting.  I'm surprised that changed from Oracle 11 to 12.  I can say that even putting a primary key constraint on the column in the view did not solve the problem in Oracle 11.