# Query regarding PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I have table named CUST where CUSTNO field is primary key and its data type is number. I have created a view on top of the table where also CUSTNO field is showing as NOT NULLABLE in attribute list of view. But when I am explicitly typecasting this CUSTNO column to string inside view, the column is showing as NULLABLE in view attribute list. Is there any way to keep this field as NON NULLABLE even after typecasting in view? I am using Oracle 12c database.

Comment: I wouldn't know. But, why do you care? What difference does it make? Column - in a table - is still a primary key and can't contain NULL values. A view could have been VERY different from a table, contain joins, calculations, whatnot, so - unless there's some reason (you didn't tell us which) - I'd concentrate on DATA view offers.

Comment: [How to create a not null column in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11097839/266304) - does that answer your question? I can see that it might be helpful to show that a column is not nullable in a view, for users who can only see the view and not the underlying table. As you're casting the value, the virtual column approach might be appropriate here; depends why you are doing that though.

Comment: I need to publish this view as layer in ARCGIS products for which CUSTNO column need to be not null for autodetection else I need to manually select unique identifier during publishing

Comment: Well, then your options seem to be to not cast it to a string; or go down the virtual column route; or maybe turn it into a materialized view; or avoid autodetection. I can't think of any other way.